# How to get the text of the checked radio button?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, label, radio-group

I have a group of radio buttons and want to get the checked radio button, then alert the text, not only the value of it. To explain more, when the user clicks the first radio button, and then submits the form, I want the browser to alert "Desktop Case." And I want to achieve this without jQuery.

```html
<form action="" name="form1">
    <label for="radio400">Desktop Case</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_case" value="400" id="radio400"/>

    <label for="radio401">Mini Tower</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_case" value="401" id="radio401"/>

    <label for="radio402">Full Tower</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_case" value="402" id="radio402"/>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="btn_submit" onclick="update_order_onclick()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You may find your answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709617/how-do-i-get-the-label-of-the-selected-radio-button-using-javascript

Comment: @Blauharley: note that you can flag these types of questions as duplicates, which sends this question to a queue for community review (hey, you get a shiny badge for it!).

Comment: The linked article uses a loop to find the checked input.  `querySelectot` is fairly universal and a more practical method.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for your example.  It uses CSS selectors to target the checked input.  Based on its id, the appropriate label is found:

```js
function update_order_onclick() {
  var value= 'Nothing selected',
      selected= document.querySelector('input[name="rad_case"]:checked'),
      selection= document.querySelector('#selection');
  
  if(selected) {
    value= document.querySelector('label[for="'+selected.id+'"]').innerHTML;
  }

  selection.innerHTML= value;
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="form1">
    <label for="radio400">Desktop Case</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_case" value="400" id="radio400"/>
    <br>

    <label for="radio401">Mini Tower</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_case" value="401" id="radio401"/>
    <br>

    <label for="radio402">Full Tower</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rad_case" value="402" id="radio402"/>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="btn_submit" onclick="update_order_onclick()"/>
</form>

<div id="selection"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we create a function to loop through the radio buttons group we have, and checks if it is checked or not.

```js
        function get_radio_val(form, name)
        {
            var val;
            var radios = form.elements[name];
            for (var i =0; i < radios.length; i++)
            {
                if (radios[i].checked)
                {
                    val = radios[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return val;
        }
```

Then we write the function that will be executed on `onclick` event.

```js
        function update_order_onclick()
        {
            var val = get_radio_val(document.form1, 'rad_case');
            var val_id = val.id;
            var selector = 'label[for=' + val_id + ']';
            var label = document.querySelector(selector);
            var label_text = label.innerHTML;
            alert(label_text);
        }
```

The thing that helped us here, is that the label `for` attribute has to be the same value as the radio button `id` and that's how we selected it in the function above.

Answer (score 0):

simply do the following:

```
var checked = document.querySelector('input:checked'); 
var id = checked?checked.id:'bla';
var lab = document.querySelector('label[for='+id+']');
var lab_text = lab?lab.textContent:'';
```

Comment: That's good, but it will cause a syntax error if nothing is checked.  You should also target the input with `name="rad_case"` in case there are other inputs in the full application.

Comment: of course you can do `var id = document.querySelector('input:checked').id || 'bla';` to avoid the syntax error

Comment: I think that will still throw an error, because null doesn't have an id.

Comment: ok my fault, `var checked = document.querySelector('input:checked'); var id = checked?checked.id:'bla'`

Comment: just edited the answer to the precise version :)

Comment: You dodn't saw , I've posted a precise version, which will show no errors ... but the initial thing was just to show the idea, not to solve all the problems, check the corrected answer.

Comment: Yep, I saw it afterwards and deleted my comment.