# Not getting the value of Radio input Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

am not able to get the values of radio button input

```js
let movieValue = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
movieValue.forEach(radio => {
  if (radio.checked) {
    console.log(radio.value)
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="movie-list" class="pick-movie">Please Select the Movie:</label>
<br>
<div class="movies">
  <input type="radio" value="18" class="moves" name="movie-list"> Fast and Furious-9- 18 USD</input>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="14" class="moves" name="movie-list"> Joker - 14 USD</input>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="15" class="moves" name="movie-list"> Spider-Man -15 USD</input>
</div>
<br>
```

when i did this....nothing is displaying on console...just blank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [addeventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to check for radio value when you click on that radio button.

You were just using `forEach` function which will **not** `check` for `checked` value because you do not have any `checked` `attr` applied to any of the `radio` buttons you have.

So you need to use `addeventListener` with a `change` event to see where you have `clicked` at to display its `value`.

Also, you do not need to use this => `</input`> to close an `input` element you can just use `/>`

**Live Demo:**

```js
let movieValue = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
movieValue.forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (radio.checked) {
      console.log(radio.value + " : " + radio.nextElementSibling.innerText)
    }
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<label for="movie-list" class="pick-movie">Please Select the Movie:</label>
<br>
<div class="movies">
  <input type="radio" value="18" id="movie1" class="moves" name="movie-list">
  <label for="movie1"> Fast and Furious-9- 18 USD </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="14" id="movie2" class="moves" name="movie-list">
  <label for="movie2"> Joker - 14 USD</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="15" id="movie3" class="moves" name="movie-list">
  <label for="movie3"> Spider-Man -15 USD</label>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: thank you very much..it worked...and can you please tell me,,,,is there any way to take name of that movie from that radio.....that is i also want to get the name of the movie from that input...for example...if i click on  first..i need 18 as value and fast and furious also

Comment: @kaki55 See my answer now! Its showing the name of the movie as well. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the grey checkmark in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  let movieValue = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

  movieValue.forEach((movie) => {
    movie.addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (movie.checked) {
        console.log(movie.value);
      }

    });

  })


});
```

```html
<label for="movie-list" class="pick-movie">Please Select the Movie:</label>
<br>
<div class="movies">
  <input type="radio" value="18" class="moves" name="movie-list"> Fast and Furious-9- 18 USD</input>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="14" class="moves" name="movie-list"> Joker - 14 USD</input>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="15" class="moves" name="movie-list"> Spider-Man -15 USD</input>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: To get the text yuou have to modify your HTML adding label to it as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709617/how-do-i-get-the-label-of-the-selected-radio-button-using-javascript

Comment: actually what my aim is ,,,,,,,,when i click on a radio button.....i need to get two values

one is the value and other is the laballed.....that meants..when i click on first....as a value i get  18 USD and on the booking summary i need to show the movie name also..how can i do that

Comment: In that requirement you may store data in an array and fetch the movie name.